# scheme:: contract violation: recursive procedure

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

I have a requirement to write a scheme procedure that takes a list as a parameter, which defines points awarded, player A score, and player B score.  The function should determine who is the winner based on the scores:

For example, this the list of lists of scores I use below:

```
(define scores '(
                 (5 . (5 . 3)) ; points awarded = (car (car scores)) 5; player A score = cadr (car scores)) 5; player B score (cddr (car scores)) 3;
                 (5 . (6 . 2))
                 (5 . (8 . 4))
                 (5 . (5 . 1))))
```

So just to clarify, breaking down the first list in the list:

5 = points awarded `(car (car scores))  ;`

A = Player A Score `(cadr (car scores)) ;` (which is 5 on the first element, 6 on the 2nd, etc.)

B = Player B Score `(cddr (car scores)) ;` (which is 3 on the first element, 2 on the 2nd, etc.)

The problem is I have made a recursive function which blows up on the 1st iteration of the recursion.  But I don't understand why?

```
#lang scheme

(define (game-winner scores)  
  (define A 0)
  (define B 0)
  (cond
    ((empty? scores) '()))
  (if ( > (cadr (car scores)) (cddr (car scores)) )
      (+ A (car (car scores)))
      (+ B (car (car scores))))
  (game-winner (cdr scores)))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: ()
```

The part that confuses me is that when I simulate running through the 1st iteration of the recursion and get the values the function *should* have, I get correct values:

```
;first loop through function

    (car (car scores))  ; 5
    (cadr (car scores)) ; 5
    (cddr (car scores)) ; 3

;second loop (1st recursive call)

    (cadr (car (cdr scores))) ; 6
    (cddr (car (cdr scores))) ; 2
```

So if I don't understand why it's blowing up?  It should work in the same way as the first call before the recursion.  But I obviously am missing something.  Any ideas?

**P.S.**
if I just return the A or B instead of the recursive call I get 0:

```
(define (game-winner scores)  
  (define A 0)
  (define B 0)
  (cond
    ((empty? scores) '()))
  (if ( > (cadr (car scores)) (cddr (car scores)) )
      (+ A (car (car scores)))
      (+ B (car (car scores))))
  A)
```

**OUTPUT:**
0

How come the value of A (which should be 5) after the first call doesn't show when I oupout A? Is `A` only in scope of the `if` loop? If so, how do I get it to exist outside that scope?

based on feedback from @Sylwester I modified by procedure to:

```
#lang scheme

(define (game-winner scores)  
  (define A 0)
  (define B 0)
  (cond
    ((empty? scores) '())
    (( > (cadr (car scores)) (cddr (car scores)))    
     (cons (+ A (car (car scores))) (game-winner (cdr scores))))
    (cons (+ B (car (car scores))) (game-winner (cdr scores)))))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(5 5 5 5)
```

So I feel like I'm getting closer.  But I need to be able to add these all together for A or for B and output the winner (A or B).  How do I build on top of this to get that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code has a lot of dead code that is never used no matter what is the outcome and in the end the last expression will do `(cdr scores)` no matter if it's empty or not.

```
(define (game-winner scores)  
  ;; Two constants that never change from 0
  (define A 0)
  (define B 0)

  ;; Dead code. Werther it's '() or #<undefined>
  (cond
    ((empty? scores) '()))

  ;; Dead code. Becomes (+ 0 (car scores)) but never used
  (if ( > (cadr (car scores)) (cddr (car scores)) )
      (+ A (car (car scores)))  ; + never mutates A
      (+ B (car (car scores)))) ; + never mutates B

  ;; Infinite recursion. Happens no matter what is the outcome of the dead code
  (game-winner (cdr scores)))
```

So when you write a `cond` or `if` it should handle all the things that happen so that it is the last expression:

```
(define (game-winner scores)
  ; local defines
  (define some-var some-expression)
  ...

  ; one expression, the result of this is the result of the procedure.
  (if (empty? scores)
      '()
      (if ....)))
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of a recursion using arguments to accumulate the scores and in the end determine who has the highest score:

```
(define (game-winner scores)
  (let loop ((scores scores) (a 0) (b 0))
    (if (empty? scores)
        (cond ((> a b) 'A)
              ((< a b) 'B)
              (else 'TIE)))
        (loop (cdr scores)
              (+ a (cadar scores))
              (+ b (cddar scores))))))

(game-winner scores)
; ==> A
```

Comment: thanks @Sylwester I'm a noob.  I tried modifying my procedure (added to bottom of my original question).  I feel like I may be getting closer but still not there yet.  Any additional help you can provide please?

Comment: @mdo123 Not exactly sure how it's suppsoed to work but I've added an example of how to keep state between iterations using extra parameters.